# Getting to the left-most and right-most tab in Firefox on Windows?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Is there a way to instantly get to the left-most and right-most tab in Firefox on Vista/Windows 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows, **Ctrl+1** selects left-most tab.

---

**Ctrl+** numbers **2** - **8** selects tabs **2** - **8**.

**Ctrl+9** selects right-most tab.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, holding Alt and pressing 1 will switch to the left most tab.

On Windows, use Ctrl instead of Alt and on Mac use Cmd.

[Here](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard+shortcuts) is a list of keyboard shortcuts for Firefox.

Comment: It might not be the default behaviour, but for me Alt + 1/2 change the workspace (Ubuntu 9.10).